# why ODG glass requires 5000 min and 5000 max FPS for scanning a bar code

Tags: android, camera

We are developing application on ODG glass (just like Google glass).
Now, In application we need to scan barcodes, and due to which we need to have Camera (Video) open through the application.
Due to which Glass gets heated.
Now, for fixing this heat issue, I decided to reduce frame per second (fps), I have used camera properties

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.Parameters.html#setPreviewFpsRange(int, int)

```
public void setPreviewFpsRange (int min, int max)

Added in API level 9
Sets the minimum and maximum preview fps. This controls the rate of preview frames received in Camera.PreviewCallback. The minimum and maximum preview fps must be one of the elements from getSupportedPreviewFpsRange().

Parameters
    min the minimum preview fps (scaled by 1000).
    max the maximum preview fps (scaled by 1000).
```

Now, when I am deploying same application with less frame per second (Min 7, Max 7) in Samsung tab 3, then is working fine and I am able to scan bar code, but if I am using same fps in ODG glass, I am not able to scan bar code.
In ODG glass, I am able to scan barcode only when I am setting fps as Min 5000, Max 5000

Please advice why ODG glass requires 5000 min and 5000 max , In comparision to Samsung tab 3 this number is too bigger .

Thanks in advance !!!